# Datetime field is only recording the break date

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this code on my view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.DT_AGENDAMENTO, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })*@
    @Html.Label("Data de Agendamento", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DT_AGENDAMENTO, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DT_AGENDAMENTO, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

And this on my controller

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "ID_SOLIC_RELATORIO,ID_RELATORIO,ID_USUARIO,DT_SOLICITACAO,DT_AGENDAMENTO,DT_GERACAO,BL_RELATORIO")] POC_SOLIC_RELATORIO pOC_SOLIC_RELATORIO)
{ 
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.POC_SOLIC_RELATORIO.Add(pOC_SOLIC_RELATORIO);
        //pOC_SOLIC_RELATORIO.BL_RELATORIO = AbrirExecutavelExtrairPdf();
        pOC_SOLIC_RELATORIO.DT_SOLICITACAO = DateTime.Now;
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.ID_RELATORIO = new SelectList(db.POC_RELATORIO, "ID_RELATORIO", "NM_RELATORIO", pOC_SOLIC_RELATORIO.ID_RELATORIO);
    return View(pOC_SOLIC_RELATORIO);
}
```

How can I do to record Date and Time, but not DateTime.Now. This date and time I fill in my view.

```
pOC_SOLIC_RELATORIO.DT_AGENDAMENTO = ?????
```

Result from Dev Tools of the google chrome9Network tab)

> __RequestVerificationToken:Z47UXlBh3Rjsi-RLUlmfzW48I62n2DXP9j_FOVFpVratuOQc9gIX4yE_4Pag03_Lk7occ4uRsKoegFlHf6oWyyy02DTkphk3mENPjyoQXWU1
>   ID_SOLIC_RELATORIO:3 ID_RELATORIO:1 ID_USUARIO:3
>   DT_AGENDAMENTO:09/11/2015

Comment: Is the new entry pOC_SOLIC_RELATORIO  sucesfully saved in the Database?

Comment: @MathiasF, yes, but this way, for example: 09/11/2015 00:00:00 and not 09/11/2015 10:45:01

Comment: Check what gets posted with F12 tools in Network tab. Does the request contain the Timepart of the date?

Comment: @MathiasF, using the dev tools of the chrome I have this: <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field DT_AGENDAMENTO must be a date." data-val-required="O campo DT_AGENDAMENTO é obrigatório." 
id="DT_AGENDAMENTO" name="DT_AGENDAMENTO" type="datetime" value="">

Comment: This is the Elements tab. Check the Network tab when you submit the form.

Comment: What do I must see on the Network tab?

Comment: I edited my post and I put the result of the Dev Tools of chrome

Comment: @MathiasF, my code is correct. If I do I fill in the date manually, there is no such as the system needs the hour. It is necessary I pass the time for him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Timepart of the DT_AGENDAMENTO  is not rendered in the resulting  Html. The default Editor for DateTime renders it. If it is not displayed in the page it cant be posted and saved (unless you use a hidden formfield for that).

Use the standart ASP.NET MVC Editor that displays the Time.